# Is Laravel Sanctum suitable to give API access to Third-party server?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

We built an API (which currently contains just a single route) to give access to specific data to another company we are working with.

The API calls this other company performs to our endpoint are server-side.
The API has been created with `Laravel 8`.

To give more context to the question, our system gathers coordinates that are sent by our GPS devices, and we want to give access to the coordinates of a specific set of GPS devices to the other company.
The coordinates are stored in our database, and the API route is just doing a SELECT query which is only allowed to access the data of these specific devices.

Searching around the internet, I saw that `Laravel Sanctum` can help providing `API tokens` to consume an API. My question is, can we use `Laravel Sanctum` for the current workflow? Is it suitable?

The examples on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#token-abilities) demonstrate we can do something like this:

```
$user->createToken('token-name', ['server:update'])->plainTextToken;
```

But, in my case, there is no `user` for the other company. If Laravel Sanctum is ok for that, should I create a specific user representing this company? or maybe another Model (and database table) just for companies? Even if we only have one in our case.

Answer (score 1):

A token can be generated for any model that has `HasApiTokens` trait.

Since you need it for authentication purpose, I think the easiest solution is to create a user that represents the company and generate a token for that user.

This way, if the user call the API with a correct token, Sanctum will authenticate the user and you can get the user using `Auth::user()` in the API action method.